# codeigniter3 multilanguage app based url abbreviation conflict with route alias

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

i have a codeigniter v3 based app, with 5 languages (ar,en,ru,es,fr) , arabic is the default one,
this is ( add funds ) page links :

```
app.com/add_funds  
app.com/en/add_funds
app.com/ru/add_funds
app.com/es/add_funds
app.com/fr/add_funds
```

everything work as expected ,
but when i set an alias for some routes 404 apear !

$route['deposit'] = 'add_funds/index';

```
app.com/add_funds          // ok
app.com/en/add_funds       // ok
app.com/ru/add_funds       // ok
app.com/es/add_funds       // ok
app.com/fr/add_funds       // ok

app.com/deposit            // ok
app.com/en/deposit         // 404
app.com/ru/deposit         // 404
app.com/es/deposit         // 404
app.com/fr/deposit         // 404
```

my code:

routes.php :

```
$route['default_controller']       = 'home';
$route['(\w{2})/(.*)']             = '$2';
$route['(\w{2})']                  = $route['default_controller'];
$route['404_override']             = 'custom_page/page_404';
$route['translate_uri_dashes']     = false;
$route['deposit']                  = 'add_funds/index';
```

.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L,QSA] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

base controller function :

```
function init_app_lang(){
        
    global $URI;
    $CI = &get_instance();
    $supported_langs = ['en'=>'english','ru'=>'russian','es'=>'spanish','fr'=>'french'];
        
    $uri_abbr = $URI->segment(1);
    if ( isset($supported_langs[$uri_abbr]) && strlen($uri_abbr) == 2 ) {

        $langDefault = $supported_langs[$uri_abbr];
        set_session('langCurrent', $langDefault);

    }else{

        $langDefault = "arabic";
        set_session('langCurrent', $langDefault);

    }

}
```

thanks && sorry about my english

Answer (score 0):

simple alias issue fixed by replacing the $val ($alias key) variable via its $value from the routes array ,

```
if( isset( $this->routes[$val]) ){
    $this->_set_request(explode('/', $this->routes[$val]));
}else{
    $this->_set_request(explode('/', $val));
}
```

but alias with $params still get 404

`$route['order/(:num)'] = 'order/view/$1';`

**Router.php**

```
/**
* Parse Routes
*
* Matches any routes that may exist in the config/routes.php file
* against the URI to determine if the class/method need to be remapped.
*
* @return   void
*/
protected function _parse_routes()
{
    // Turn the segment array into a URI string
    $uri = implode('/', $this->uri->segments);

    // Get HTTP verb
    $http_verb = isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) ? strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) : 'cli';

    // Loop through the route array looking for wildcards
    foreach ($this->routes as $key => $val) {
        // Check if route format is using HTTP verbs
        if (is_array($val)) {
            $val = array_change_key_case($val, CASE_LOWER);
            if (isset($val[$http_verb])) {
                $val = $val[$http_verb];
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }

        // Convert wildcards to RegEx
        $key = str_replace([':any', ':num'], ['[^/]+', '[0-9]+'], $key);

        // Does the RegEx match?
        if (preg_match('#^' . $key . '$#', $uri, $matches)) {
            // Are we using callbacks to process back-references?
            if (!is_string($val) && is_callable($val)) {
                // Remove the original string from the matches array.
                array_shift($matches);

                // Execute the callback using the values in matches as its parameters.
                $val = call_user_func_array($val, $matches);
            }
            // Are we using the default routing method for back-references?
            elseif (strpos($val, '$') !== false && strpos($key, '(') !== false) {
                $val = preg_replace('#^' . $key . '$#', $val, $uri);

                if (isset($this->routes[$val])) {
                    $this->_set_request(explode('/', $this->routes[$val]));
                } else {
                    $this->_set_request(explode('/', $val));
                }

                return;
            }
        }

        // If we got this far it means we didn't encounter a
        // matching route so we'll set the site default route
        $this->_set_request(array_values($this->uri->segments));
    }
}
```

Comment: @francisco the suggested edit not working , $route['order/(:num)'] = 'order/view/$1'  or  $route['tickets/(:num)'] = 'tickets/view/$1' **  is not matched  **

Comment: I have edited just [text](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75788820/revisions) for psr-12 and identation. Check if you are doing with CI4 because this is old